# How do I express a guarantee that one thread will outlive another, allowing me to share references without 'static?

Tags: multithreading, rust, thread-safety

I'm working on a task scheduling framework in Rust that uses work stealing between executors. Each executor has it's own thread which I have spawned using code that looks like this:

`let t_handle = thread::spawn(move || {...}`

Abstractly, there must be a way for this thread to be able to see the work queues of other threads and perform a stealing operation on that queue.

The way I'm doing this right now is by passing a function (`Fn()`) into the struct's `new` method called `on_steal` which closes over a borrow of `vec<Stealer>`.

Rust yells at me in two places:

- First it wants a lifetime parameter for `on_steal`, and specifically it's asking for `static`.
- After blessing that `on_steal` with `'static`, the lifetime for my borrow of `vec<Stealer>` becomes an issue.

The solution I have currently is to wrap my `vec<Stealer>` in a `Arc<mutex<_>>`, which is fine. But I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution for specifying lifetime params of threads in Rust.

I'm looking to express some kind of guarantee that one thread will outlive another, thus allowing me to lend out references from the more longevous thread to the shorter lived thread without requiring those refs to be static.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] or your current solution. It's much better to have some code than to make guesses.

Comment: Have you seen [Rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon): *Simple work-stealing parallelism for Rust*

Comment: I believe your question to be answered by the answers in [Lifetime troubles sharing references between threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28654978/155423), [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/155423), and [How do I share a generic struct between threads using Arc<Mutex<MyStruct<T>>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40035731/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences (in addition to providing a MCVE).

Comment: Look for scoped threads and scoped threadpools

Answer (score 0):

There is no trivial way to do this.

Any `F` passed to `thread::spawn` must be `'static`; you cannot assert a lifetime on the thread, or bound it to a specific scope; the function you supply must be static, so you cannot use a closure with a custom lifetime for this purpose.

The work around for this is to `unsafe` all the things; here are two typical examples:

https://github.com/Kimundi/scoped-threadpool-rs/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L209

https://github.com/crossbeam-rs/crossbeam-utils/blob/master/src/scoped.rs#L326

Practically speaking, there is no significantly more 'elegant' solution than just using `Arc`. You could also try coordinating using channels, using an existing solution like [scoped_threadpool](https://crates.io/crates/scoped_threadpool) or write your own, but I strongly advise against re-inventing the wheel and writing your own implementation using unsafe, its very easy to mess up.

Personally, I think something like [Is it possible to send closures via channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557152/is-it-possible-to-send-closures-via-channels) would suit your purpose, but without more details, its hard to know.